# Electro magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

If an emf is produced in a dc motor, would it be possible to use the motor somehow as a generator or source, taking power out of it rather than putting power into it? How might this be done?

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233089/104696)

Comment: bicycle lights come to mind., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo

Answer (score 0):

Yes an electric motor will also work as a generator. That is, you can connect it to a load and when you rotate the motor it will push a current though the load. There is a thorough explanation of this in [Farcher's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233101/1325) to [Eddy current induce emf](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233089/eddy-current-induce-emf).

However designing a generator for maximum efficiency is a complicated business, and your motor will not be as efficient a generator as a generator that has been specifically designed for the purpose. The differences between motors and generators are explored in [How does the electric motor and generator vary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11107/how-does-the-electric-motor-and-generator-vary)